# Usage of pointers through Queue - FreeRTOS

Tags: c, freertos

I am used to use using queue with structures but I don't understand what the advantage is to give pointers to a queue.

The queue only copies pointer and not the data, and in this case I have to manage the memory access to avoid conflicts.
Is it better to use mutex or semaphore to access at the same memory part from different tasks ?

I want to find the best way to share "big" structures between my tasks.

Answer (score 0):

from the FreeRtos documentation, it suggests that passing pointers to large structures is fine. For inter-task memory access, the safest option is to use locks and the memory that is referenced should not be a dynamic memory.

```
QueueHandle_t xQueue1, xQueue2;

    /* Create a queue capable of containing 10 unsigned long values. */
    xQueue1 = xQueueCreate( 10, sizeof( unsigned long ) );

    if( xQueue1 == NULL )
    {
        /* Queue was not created and must not be used. */
    }

    /* Create a queue capable of containing 10 pointers to AMessage
    structures.  These are to be queued by pointers as they are
    relatively large structures. */
    xQueue2 = xQueueCreate( 10, sizeof( struct AMessage * ) );

    if( xQueue2 == NULL )
    {
        /* Queue was not created and must not be used. */
    }
```

Page 154 of the [Mastering the FreeRTOS Real Time Kernel - a Hands On Tutorial Guide](https://www.freertos.org/fr-content-src/uploads/2018/07/161204_Mastering_the_FreeRTOS_Real_Time_Kernel-A_Hands-On_Tutorial_Guide.pdf) also provides some insights.

Comment: So the queue seems useless if I use a mutex or semaphore to lock my structure.

Comment: a queue can pass a pointer to your structure, or it can pass a duplicate copy of your structure as a whole. If you have available memory to pass a copy of your entire structure then it's safer to send it as a whole instead of passing the pointer where you may have to take care of mutex or semaphore.